# odom z pose.orientation to degree

Tags: navigation, odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I have the odom pose.orientation data:

orientation:
x: 0.0
y: 0.0
z: -0.00128386864513
w: 0.99999917584

And i want the YAW (Z) data in degree format. How can i transform it to degree?

Thanks for your help!
Bence

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204206/odom-z-pose.orientation-to-degree/) by [Beni](https://answers.ros.org/users/21771/beni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a quaternion. The z component of a quaternion is NOT the yaw. You need to convert this to euler angles or similar. `tf::getYaw` can do that for you. The angles package has `angles::to_degrees` to convert the resulting radians to degrees.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1